# Find all the abstract base classes that a class is registered with

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, subclass, abc

How can I find all the abstract base classes that a given class is a "virtual subclass" of?

In other words, I'm looking for a magic function `virtual_base_classes()` that does something like this:

```
>>> for cls in virtual_base_classes(list):
>>>   print(cls)
<class 'collections.abc.MutableSequence'>
<class 'collections.abc.Sequence'>
<class 'collections.abc.Sized'>
<class 'collections.abc.Iterable'>
<class 'collections.abc.Container'>
```

(I don't know all the `abc` classes that `list` is registered with, so the above example may not be complete.)

Note that not every abstract base class will be defined in `collections.abc`. There is a module `abc` (distinct from `collections.abc`) which provides the metaclass `ABCMeta`. Any class that is an instance of `ABCMeta` supports registration of "virtual subclasses" using the standard interface (the `register` method). There's nothing that stops someone (whether a programmer or Python library) from creating an instance of `ABCMeta` that does not belong in `collections.abc`.

Comment: A class doesn't "know" that it has been registered as a virtual subclass of some ABC, so you can't find all ABCs starting from the class. Meanwhile, Python doesn't provide a means to locate every class that has `ABCMeta` as its metaclass (unless there's a piece of introspection you can do to find all classes, including those whose module is no longer in `sys.modules` due to a module reload). So you can't find all of your type's ABCs starting from a list of all existing ABCs either.

Comment: @SteveJessop thanks, this makes perfect sense. I suppose, strictly speaking, I can find all the reachable classes by iterating through the stack frames - but I didn't mean to go that far.

Comment: heh, yes, with enough effort you could iterate over every object in the Python runtime, testing each in turn to see if it's an ABC and if so whether your target type `issubclass`.

Comment: @SteveJessop There's `object.__subclasses__()` if you just want types, or `gc.get_objects()` for everything except immutable leafs. So I answered this properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `issubclass` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> import collections.abc
>>> import inspect
>>> [v for k, v in vars(collections.abc).items()
                                  if inspect.isclass(v) and issubclass(list, v) ]
[<class 'collections.abc.Container'>,
 <class 'collections.abc.Sequence'>,
 <class 'collections.abc.MutableSequence'>,
 <class 'collections.abc.Iterable'>,
 <class 'collections.abc.Sized'>
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted the list of all the abstract base classes - rather than checking one by one. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Thanks. That would work for `collections.abc`, but not in general. I'm updating the question to explain, since the comment doesn't have enough space.

Comment: Given Steve's comment, your answer is the best there is :)

Comment: anyway that i can achieve the same on python 2.7.x ?

Comment: @RasikaPerera Nothing in either answer is fundamentally restricted to python3, but hopefully you've given up on python2 in the years since you wrote that comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is, in fact, possible. The trick is to wrap the `ABCMeta.register` function, and scan `object.__subclasses__()` recursively to find anything registered before this module is imported.

```
''' Allow listing virtual bases from ABCMeta.

    Copyright © 2018 Ben Longbons <b.r.longbons@gmail.com>
    Licensed under GPL3+ or CC BY-SA 3.0+

    IMPORTANT CAVEATS:

    1. C++ programmers, remember "virtual base" means something
    different in Python!

    2. Importing this module as soon as possible, before creating any
    threads, and don't create bound references to `ABCMeta.register`.

    3. It's possible for there to be no valid MRO.

    4. This can't handle __subclasshook__ (for Callable etc).

    5. The MRO can change any time that `register` is called.
'''


import abc
import threading


tracked_bases = {}
tracker_lock = threading.Lock()
global_virtual_mro_calculator = None
global_virtual_mro_calculator_token = None


def dotted_name(obj, *, relative=None):
    ''' Fully-qualified name of a class, function, or module.
    '''
    if relative is not None:
        relative = relative.__module__
    name = getattr(obj, '__qualname__', obj.__name__)
    # modules themselves have just a __name__
    mod = getattr(obj, '__module__', None)
    if mod is not None and mod != relative:
        return '%s.%s' % (mod, name)
    return name

def sorted_types(collection):
    return sorted(collection, key=lambda cls: dotted_name(cls))

def sanity_check():
    standard_calculator = MroCalculator()
    virtual_mro_calculator = get_global_virtual_mro_calculator()
    for t in sorted_types(hunt_types(object)):
        std_mro = standard_calculator.mro(t)
        assert tuple(std_mro) == t.__mro__, (std_mro, t.__mro__)
        virt_mro = virtual_mro_calculator.mro(t)
        assert set(virt_mro) >= set(t.__mro__)

def bases_string(cls, *, virtual=False, relative=None):
    assert cls is not relative
    rv = [dotted_name(base, relative=relative) for base in cls.__bases__]
    if virtual:
        for base in tracked_bases.get(cls, ()):
            rv.append('+' + dotted_name(base, relative=relative))
    if len(rv) <= 1:
        return ''
    return '(%s)' % ', '.join(rv)

def dump_types(cls, *, virtual=False, depth=0, relative=None, sigil=''):
    name = dotted_name(cls, relative=relative)
    bases = bases_string(cls, virtual=virtual, relative=relative)
    if isinstance(cls, abc.ABCMeta):
        sigil += '!'
    print('  ' * depth, sigil, name, bases, sep='')
    depth += 1

    for child in sorted_types(type(cls).__subclasses__(cls)):
        dump_types(child, virtual=virtual, depth=depth, relative=cls)
    if virtual:
        if isinstance(cls, abc.ABCMeta):
            for child in sorted_types(cls._abc_registry):
                dump_types(child, virtual=virtual, depth=depth, relative=cls, sigil='+')

def hunt_types(cls, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = {cls}
    # There are usually only about 500 classes at startup, and the walk
    # finishes in under ~0.5 ms on CPython and ~0.05 ms on PyPy.
    #
    # Using `gc.get_referrers(abc.ABCMeta)` would take about the same
    # time on CPython, but it's *much* slower on PyPy (~50 ms).
    for scls in type(cls).__subclasses__(cls):
        if scls in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(scls)
        hunt_types(scls, seen)
    return seen

def _register_types(cls):
    assert isinstance(cls, abc.ABCMeta)
    # This order is also nondeterministic, but this one doesn't matter.
    for vscls in cls._abc_registry:
        tracked_bases.setdefault(vscls, []).append(cls)

def _install():
    with tracker_lock:
        old_register = abc.ABCMeta.register
        def abc_tracker_register(cls, subclass):
            with tracker_lock:
                if issubclass(subclass, cls):
                    return subclass
                rv = old_register(cls, subclass)
                assert rv is subclass
                tracked_bases.setdefault(subclass, []).append(cls)
                return rv
        abc.ABCMeta.register = abc_tracker_register
        # TODO nondeterministic order - `hunt_types` returns a `set`.
        # This only matters if some class has been registered as a
        # (direct) virtual subclass of *multiple* ABCs
        for t in hunt_types(object):
            if isinstance(t, abc.ABCMeta):
                _register_types(t)
        del t


class MroCalculator:
    # Based on https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/
    # but with more flexibility.
    def __init__(self):
        self.mro_cache = {}

    def bases(self, cls):
        assert isinstance(cls, type)
        return cls.__bases__

    def merge(self, mros):
        assert isinstance(mros, list)
        for mro in mros:
            assert isinstance(mro, list)
            for cls in mro:
                assert isinstance(cls, type)

        rv = []
        while True:
            mros = [mro for mro in mros if mro]
            if not mros:
                return tuple(rv)
            for mro in mros:
                cand = mro[0]
                for m in mros:
                    if cand in m[1:]:
                        cand = None
                        break
                if cand is not None:
                    break
            if cand is None:
                bad_bases = [mro[0] for mro in mros]
                bad_base_str = ', '.join(sorted(set([dotted_name(b) for b in bad_bases])))
                raise TypeError('Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases %s' % bad_base_str)
            rv.append(cand)
            for mro in mros:
                if cand is mro[0]:
                    del mro[0]

    def mro(self, cls):
        assert isinstance(cls, type)
        rv = self.mro_cache.get(cls, None)
        if rv is not None:
            return rv

        bases = list(self.bases(cls))
        if cls is not object:
            assert bases, cls
        rv = self.merge([[cls]] + [list(self.mro(b)) for b in bases] + [bases])
        assert cls not in self.mro_cache
        assert isinstance(rv, tuple)
        self.mro_cache[cls] = rv
        return rv

class VirtualMroCalculator(MroCalculator):
    def bases(self, cls):
        super_bases = super().bases(cls)
        more_bases = tuple(tracked_bases.get(cls, ()))
        # Virtual bases must come *first* in the MRO to handle:
        #
        #   class _io.BytesIO(_io._BufferedIOBase): pass
        #   class io.BufferedIOBase(_io._BufferedIOBase): pass
        #   io.BufferedIOBase.register(_io.BytesIO)
        #
        # This also occurs in _frozen_importlib_external.
        return more_bases + super_bases


def get_global_virtual_mro_calculator():
    global global_virtual_mro_calculator
    global global_virtual_mro_calculator_token
    # The token can't change while we hold the lock.
    with tracker_lock:
        current_token = abc.get_cache_token()
        if current_token != global_virtual_mro_calculator_token:
            global_virtual_mro_calculator_token = current_token
            global_virtual_mro_calculator = VirtualMroCalculator()
        return global_virtual_mro_calculator

def virtual_mro(cls):
    virtual_mro_calculator = get_global_virtual_mro_calculator()
    # This may or may not see (and cache) concurrent changes.
    # The important part is that *future* calls will see them.
    return virtual_mro_calculator.mro(cls)


_install()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sanity_check()
    dump_types(object, virtual=True)
```